# undefined is not a function: auto-executing function the cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

Is there something wrong with this line below?

`if (!$imgs.length) {return $.Deferred.resolve().promise();}`

I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` console error.

**Context**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

(function($) {
    // Function to allow an event to fire after all images are loaded
    $.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {

        $imgs = this.find('img[src!=""]');
        // if there's no images, just return an already resolved promise
        if (!$imgs.length) {return $.Deferred.resolve().promise();}

        // for each image, add a deferred object to the array which resolves when the image is loaded
        var dfds = [];
        $imgs.each(function(){

            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            dfds.push(dfd);
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){dfd.resolve();}
            img.src = this.src;

        });

        // return a master promise object which will resolve when all the deferred objects have resolved
        // IE - when all the images are loaded
        return $.when.apply($,dfds);

    }
})(jQuery);

});
```

Comment: Why don't you pur `$imgs.length` like this `$($imgs).length`

Comment: I'd try to look at the `this.find` line, and not deferreds. Try changing that to `$(this).find()`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @skip405 Just tried that but unfortunately the error is still there.

Comment: Is error hitting on `if($imgs.length)` line??? **EDIT:** can you provide the html if possible??

Comment: And if you change `$.Deferred.resolve().promise();` to `false` will the error be there?

Comment: @skip405 Yes, the error is still there. This is the [live site](http://staging.keebs.com) if it helps at all. The console error pops up right when the site loads.